# Which relation symbol goes between $F_m$ and $\phi^m$?

Tags: asymptotics, fibonacci-numbers, golden-ratio

I have already asked a similar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3151260/607539) where the tilde notation was used (and context can be taken from there). Now I think that tilde is not the correct symbol to go between these two functions since tilde is defined as $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{f(n)}{g(n)} = 1$, but the functions in question actually tend to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$, though I might be wrong.

So in terms of asymptotic analysis can anyone help me understand in which relation are these two functions exactly?

Comment: You could use Big Theta ($\Theta$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual approach is to write $F_m\in\Theta(\phi^m)$ or, in an abuse of notation, $F_m=\Theta(\phi^m)$. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau_notations) for some other common relations; $\mathcal{O}$ and $\Omega$, in particular, can be accurately used here.

Comment: Can one say that $F_m\sim\phi^m$ is not correct or it can be somehow used?

Comment: @MichaelMunta It is incorrect, because it implies a ratio of limit $1$. I can understand someone saying, "let's redefine it to not care about the exact limit", but we already have notation for that weaker statement; it's worth keeping the strong meaning of $\sim$ for when we'd like to say it.

Comment: Isn't big O just giving the upper bound on the function?

Comment: @MichaelMunta My mistake! I've edited my answer.

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but on the link you have provided where all notations are listed there is a formal definition column. I am wondering whether the constants there like $k, n_0$ etc need to be integers or they can be any real number?

Comment: @Munta There shouldn't be an integer requirement.